# Thymeleaf loop with names from MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Trying to get names from a database to display on web page but getting a blank page. Let me know what I'm doing wrong, app does work so there isn't a stack trace worth posting

Simple Thymeleaf view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:text="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en"></head>
<body th:each="customer: ${customers}">
<h2 th:text="${customer}"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model){
     List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.findAll();
     model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
    return "list-customers";
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerDAO extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {
    public List<Customer> findAll();

}
```

Impl:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public abstract class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
       return customerDAO.findAll();
        }   
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer(){}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String company){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = company;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.email = company;
    }
}
```

Comment: With `<body th:each="customer: ${customers}">`you create multiple body tags in one HTML. This is not allowed in HTML. Keep the body-tag clean and use e.g. an extra div-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be updated to something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:text="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en"></head>
<body>
  <div th:each="customer: ${customers}">
    <h2 th:text="${customer}"></h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will call the `toString()` method on each of your `customer` objects.

If you're still seeing an empty list, you can add a breakpoint to your query calls and run your debugger or simply log the count/elements to see what your repository/database is returning.